# java.lang.IllegalStateException in retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using **retrofit 2.0** `Gson` data not getting

When i check Postman  i am getting response below

```
{
    "name": "Yashodhan Communication",
    "zone": "9-Belgaum",
    "tsm_name": "Tarun Patil",
    "asm_name": "Shivakumar Patil"
}
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

**APIClient Client**

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://vehiclerescue.in/ideadarpan_beta/")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit;

    }
```

This is **Pojo class**

```
public class Appuser_Pojoclass {


    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private  String name;

    @SerializedName("zone")
    @Expose
    private  String zone;

    @SerializedName("tsm_name")
    @Expose
    private  String tsm_name;

    @SerializedName("asm_name")
    @Expose
    private  String  asm_name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getZone() {
        return zone;
    }

    public void setZone(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public String getTsm_name() {
        return tsm_name;
    }

    public void setTsm_name(String tsm_name) {
        this.tsm_name = tsm_name;
    }

    public String getAsm_name() {
        return asm_name;
    }

    public void setAsm_name(String asm_name) {
        this.asm_name = asm_name;
    }
}
```

**Activity class**

```
 private void fetchAllAppUserdata()
    {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Log.d("getauthkeydisplay","**** "+Idea_Urban.getInstance().get_Authkeyvalues());

        ideaInterface.get_AppUsers(Idea_Urban.getInstance().get_Authkeyvalues()).enqueue(new Callback<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>> call, Response<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>> response) {

                if(app_users != null)
                {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    app_users.clear();
                }
                if(response.body()!=null) {

                    app_users.addAll(response.body());

                    Log.d("appuserresponce","*****   "+response.body());
                //    app_userDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else
                {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("failure","**** ");

                Log.d("printmetthodsfailure","faiure"+call.toString()   + "\n "  + t.toString());

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

I found some solution as google suggestion but i donot know how to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

So you should check you response of your code .

Your `JSON` response  is `JSONObject` ,so you should use `Call<Appuser_Pojoclass> call`

**Change**

```
Call<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>> call
```

**to**

```
Call<Appuser_Pojoclass> call
```

Comment: Sry sir it's excecuting `onFailure` method....It is not comeing inside `onResponse` method

Comment: ok if it's Json Object i should not use `List` i am correct sir..let me try

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the Call declaration,change

```
     Call<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>>
```

with

```
      Call<Appuser_Pojoclass>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your retrofit call response type is `<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>>` but your API response is not a list of `Appuser_Pojoclass`, it is simply a single object of type `Appuser_Pojoclass`.

Change type from `<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>>` to `Appuser_Pojoclass` in your retrofit call

Answer (score 1):

You probably defined your `get_AppUsers` method as something that returns `Call<List<Appuser_Pojoclass>>` instead of just `Call<Appuser_Pojoclass>` so it ends up looking for a JSON array, but then your response only contains a single JSON object which causes the error. Change `get_AppUsers` to return `Call<Appuser_Pojoclass>` and then change your callback accordingly and that should fix the problem.